# how to change a control property from another form

Tags: c#, forms

I have two forms in a windows form application. lets call them "first form" and "second form".
 i want by clikcing on a button on second form, change the property of one of the controls of the first form.  i've defined an event for this. by that i mean when i click on the second form's button, a method within the first form is called. here's the method:

```
// changes the visibility of the specified control
   public void change_visibility() 
    {
        this.new_customer_label.Visible = true;
    }
```

but when i set a breakpoint on this method and check the value after it is executed. the property has't changed. what is wrong? thanks in advance

*note*: on the second form button's click event, i also close the form.

Comment: probably because first form isn't initialized.

Answer (score 2):

So firstly, Open up `Form1.designer.cs` and change the control to `public`

`Form1` this will open Form 2.

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Owner = this;
frm2.Show();
```

`Form2` this will change the property of a control in Form 1

```
(this.Owner as Form1).label1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
class Form1 : Form {

  private Label labelInForm1;
  public string LabelText {
    get { return labelInForm1.Text; }
    set { labelInForm1.Text = value; }
  }
}

class Form2 : Form {
  Form1 form1; // Set by the property

  private Form1 Form1 {
    get { return form1; }
    set { form1 = value; }
  }

  private ChangeVisibility()
  {
    Form1.labelInForm1.Visible = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"note: on the second form button's click event, i also close the form."

Then it would probably be a better design to display the second form with ShowDialog() instead of Show().  Something like:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog(); // code STOPS here until "f2" is closed
this.new_customer_label.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the designer generates code in the 'Form1.Designer.cs' class. In there, you can see that all the controls are set private, change them to public and then try again...

Answer (score 0):

As you will search this problem on internet you will find different solutions but I think the best solution is to make controls public then you can access these controls from any form.
Follow these instructions.

1. Open your desire form whose control properties you want to access
2. Open Form.Designer.cs
3. Change the desire control class to public
4. Go to the main form where you want to access or change property
5. Write this code
   `Form Form2 objForm=new Form2();`
6. Now access your control property here
   `objForm.new_customer_label.Visible=true;`

I hope this will be helpful to you!!!